# Why do I need to use [6] to slice out the time in the following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out the distribution by hour of the day for each of the messages.

You can pull the hour out from the 'From ' line by finding the time and then splitting the string a second time using a colon.

Once you have accumulated the counts for each hour, print out the counts, sorted by hour as shown below.

```
name = input('Enter file name: ')
if len(name)<1:
    name = 'mbox-short.txt'
hand = open(name)
counts = dict()


for line in hand:
    if not line.startswith('From '):
        continue
    words = line.split(' ')
    words = words[6]
    #print(words.split(':'))
    hour = words.split(':')[0]
    counts[hour] = counts.get(hour, 0) + 1
for k,v in sorted(counts.items()):
     print(k,v)
```

I have to use [6] to slice out the time in the email. But shouldn't it be 5?

The lines from which I need to extract the hour look like this:
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 200

Comment: How can we possibly tell without seeing any data?

Comment: Could you add at least one line from the valid .csv file?

Comment: If you think 1-based you will never become World's #0 Programmer.

Comment: My best guess is that you're unaware that indexing starts at 0. You're also not taking a slice, you're indexing the list.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot the data in a hurry, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you're right the index should be 5 in this exmaple. By the way for counting there is a built-in object in `collections` module. you can rewrite your code like this:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()

name = input('Enter file name: ')
if len(name) < 1:
    name = 'mbox-short.txt'

with open(name) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('From'):
            words = line.split(' ')
            time = words[5]
            hour = time.split(':')[0]
            counter[hour] += 1
for hour, freq in sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0])):
     print(hour, freq)
```

You can also access to most common items via:

```
counter.most_common(10) # it'll show you the first 10 most common items
```